# Use ssh credentials in jenkins pipeline with ssh, scp or sftp

Tags: jenkins, ssh, jenkins-pipeline

I want to use scp/ssh to upload some files to a server. I discover that I need to use certificate-based authentication, but the question is how? Really what I want to do is to use the same sort of credentials I use with git - passworded ssh cert stored in Jenkins. However, I can't work out how to - the snippet generator has no obvious option for that.

What do others do? Is there an undocumented feature that would do this?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If you install the [SSH Agent plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/SSH+Agent+Plugin) you can use the [`ssh-agent`](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/ssh-agent/) pipeline step to run a shell script with an ssh-agent active. The `ssh-agent` takes a Jenkins credentials ID (a passworded ssh cert, like the one you have for git).

Comment: agree this is the clean solution - but getting ssh-agent working correctly on Windows is a pain IMO.

Comment: Any idea how to get a reference to the SSH credentials ID used by the project? Something like, `sshagent(credentials: [env.scm_credentials])`?

Comment: Found something that works in my case: `sshagent(credentials: scm.userRemoteConfigs.credentialsId)`. This works because my `scm` ends up being a `GitSCM` class. Probably the case for most users. https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/params/gitscm/

Answer (score 72):

```
    withCredentials([sshUserPrivateKey(credentialsId: "yourkeyid", keyFileVariable: 'keyfile')]) {
       stage('scp-f/b') {
        sh 'scp -i ${keyfile} do sth here'
       }
   }
```

Maybe this is what you want. Install `Credentials Plugin` and
`Credentials Binding Plugin`. Add some credentials and then you will get "yourkeyid", bind this credentials to keyFileVariable, passphraseVariable etc.

More details and documentation can be found on the Github site of the Jenkins [Credentials Binding Plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/credentials-binding-plugin), [Credentials Binding Plugin docs](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/credentials-binding/), [Credentials Plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/credentials-plugin), [SSH Pipeline Steps](https://github.com/jenkinsci/ssh-steps-plugin) plugin

Comment: I'd like to add that credentials used in `sh` shouldn't be placed between double quotes, but single quotes, i.e. `sh 'scp -i ${keyfile} do sth here'`. https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/#interpolation-of-sensitive-environment-variables

Comment: The perfect solution without using 3rd party modules which ends support time to time.