# How to use publish over ssh plugin in pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I would like to SSH to linux server from Jenkins hosted on windows and execute a command over in linux machine, I tried installing publish over ssh plugin and tested the connection in global config and it works fine, I don't know how to proceed next in pipeline. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Make sure to add what you have tried so far and what went wrong. Also try to include output and/or errors so we can better help you. Remember, Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service, but there are a lot of helpful people here that are willing to take a look if you make an effort to explain your problem.

Comment: the plugin help page has no information on pipelines, it has information only for other types, that is why i have clearly mentioned that i dont know how to proceed for pipeline.
https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Publish+Over+SSH+Plugin

Comment: I made a ticket for it as I'd like to know myself
https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-49728

Comment: This is a similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44377238/use-ssh-credentials-in-jenkins-pipeline-with-ssh-scp-or-sftp

Answer (score 10):

If you are using a **pipeline project** and a **Jenkinsfile**, then all you need to do is go into your project in Jenkins and click configure. In the pipeline section of the configuration, at the bottom there is a link "pipeline syntax". It will take you to the **Snippet Generator**. Its self explanatory and in our case it allows to generate "publish over ssh" snippets that you would add to your Jenkinsfile (add it to a steps section inside a stage definition). In the generator you can define what to publish, options to run a shell command, etc. [source](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/getting-started/#snippet-generator)

Answer (score 7):

In case you were looking for the syntax for a declarative pipeline (Jenkinsfile) for Publish-Over-SSH, (Instead of the scripted pipeline, which is all I could find). Here's what finally worked for me.

```
pipeline{
  agent any
  environment {
    RELEASENAME="yourProject-ci"
  }
  stages{
    stage("Get the charts..."){
        steps {checkout scm}
    }
    stage('SSH transfer') {
        steps([$class: 'BapSshPromotionPublisherPlugin']) {
            sshPublisher(
                continueOnError: false, failOnError: true,
                publishers: [
                    sshPublisherDesc(
                        configName: "kubernetes_master",
                        verbose: true,
                        transfers: [
                            sshTransfer(execCommand: "/bin/rm -rf /opt/deploy/helm"),
                            sshTransfer(sourceFiles: "helm/**",)
                        ]
                    )
                ]
            )
        }
    }
    stage('Deploy Helm Scripts'){
        steps([$class: 'BapSshPromotionPublisherPlugin']) {
            sshPublisher(
                continueOnError: false, failOnError: true,
                publishers: [
                    sshPublisherDesc(
                        configName: "kubernetes_master",
                        verbose: true,
                        transfers: [
                            sshTransfer(execCommand: "cd /opt/deploy/helm;helm upgrade ${RELEASENAME} . --install"),
                        ]
                    )
                ]
            )
        }
    }
  }
}
```

I have a checkout that happens first and then I copy some helm charts from the checkout to my kubernetes master and then run the charts.

`configName: "kubernetes_master"` is something I setup in the Publish_over_ssh plugin configuration section (Found under Manage Jenkins > Configure System) so I could reference it.   It includes a username, sshkey, destination hostname, and base directory for the destination which I put as /opt/deploy.

FYI execCommand does not use the base directory... it assumes you will use full pathing.

Hope that helps.

edit: I should probably mention that there are lots more options for the sshPublisher than what I used.  You can find them here: https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/publish-over-ssh/

Answer (score 3):

Based on levis answer, the below has worked for me.

```kotlin
stage('Deploy') {
  agent any
  steps {
    sh 'mv target/my-app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar my-app.jar'
    sshPublisher(
      continueOnError: false, 
      failOnError: true,
      publishers: [
        sshPublisherDesc(
          configName: "my-ssh-connection",
          transfers: [sshTransfer(sourceFiles: 'my-app.jar')],
          verbose: true
        )
      ]
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I got this question some time ago, and here is the answer. Change the code according to your requirement.

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    options { timestamps () }
    stages {
        stage('Publish over ssh plugin in pipeline') {
            steps([$class: 'BapSshPromotionPublisherPlugin']) {
                script {
                    List SERVERS_LIST = ["Server_1", "Server_2"]
                    for(cr_server in SERVERS_LIST){
                        sshPublisher(
                            publishers: [
                                sshPublisherDesc(
                                    configName: cr_server, 
                                    transfers: [
                                        sshTransfer(
                                            cleanRemote: false, 
                                            excludes: '', 
                                            execCommand: '', 
                                            execTimeout: 120000, 
                                            flatten: false, 
                                            makeEmptyDirs: false, 
                                            noDefaultExcludes: false, 
                                            patternSeparator: '[, ]+', 
                                            remoteDirectory: '', 
                                            remoteDirectorySDF: false, 
                                            removePrefix: '', 
                                            sourceFiles: '**/*'
                                        )
                                    ], 
                                    usePromotionTimestamp: false, 
                                    useWorkspaceInPromotion: false, 
                                    verbose: false
                                )
                            ]
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        } 
    }
}
```